# Not able to use tidyverse package after installing it

Tags: r, tidyverse

Not able to use tidyverse package after installing it.

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

> running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\CHOUDJI1\AppData\Local\R\win64-library\3.2" C:\Users\CHOUDJI1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMJl1ha/downloaded_packages/tidyverse_1.2.1.tar.gz' had status 1
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>       ‘C:\Users\CHOUDJI1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMJl1ha\downloaded_packages’

Comment: try `install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: the code is not working, same error persists

Comment: Two suggestions: update R (3.2 was last updated over a year and a half ago); and install R in a path (on windows) without spaces (e.g., not `/Program Files/...`). (`c:/R/R-3.3.2/`, for instance.) Some of the problems with spaces in the paths have included installing packages.